# use one column of excel data to find values from metadata in another workbook

Tags: excel, metadata, multiple-columns, matching

I'm new here so apologies if my question is not clear.

I've got an excel spreadsheet "master" full of metadata (columns A:BA) and aproximately 3000 rows. The data for each set is unique per row. Column E has information on file name (each file name is unique).

In another programme (programme X) that I need to use, it generates a list of filenames (e.g. as per column E) but this will only include a selection of the filenames found in column E and not necessarily in the same order.

I want a function so I can paste the filenames from "programme X" into an excel spreadsheet and match and pull the correct metadata from my "master" spreadsheet (with all the correct information per row pulled for each filename).

How do you suggest I do this?

Many thanks, any help hugely appreciated!

edstj

Comment: I should have also said that I need the metadata to be extracted in exactly the same order as the column copied from "programme X". i.e. the order of the file list taken from column X can't change.

Comment: I think i've managed to do this using fuzzy lookup. Is that the best way others would suggest?